# How to make a commonality?

Tags: python, pandas, list, subset, pandas-groupby

I'm making a *commonality table* for some data, and i need to have a subset table with the number of appearances of each value in descending order.
I have a table:

[image]

the end result for me is a list that the names do not appear, but the rows are the months with commonality, something like this:
[image]

i need it to be in descending order horizontally and vertically(number of appearance).

Comment: *intersected by the 2 lists* ... are these lists given in advance? Also, what is your desired output: 2nd or 3rd image? Please show contents of CSV files.

Comment: The 2 list are given in advance.
i'm trying to create a function that gets 1 file with all the data (like the first image), and another file with 2 columns from which i'll have my 2 lists.
my desired output is like the third image (note that the line numbers in the image are made up and not from the second image)

Comment: something like `a = pd.Series({col: dat[col].value_counts() for col in dat.columns})` followed by `for ix, val in enumerate(a): a[ix] = 100*val/val.sum()` ?

Comment: it actually did pretty good, but i'm trying to get the output in a table.
now it is in an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end what worked for me is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


# this function gets a string like: "line,num%" and returns the num in float
def take_second(elem):
    elem = float(elem[elem.find(",") + 1:elem.find("%")])
    return elem


# this function gets a list and sorts it in descending order according to the second variable of every cell
def sorting(lst):
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: take_second(x), reverse=True)
    return lst


data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('commonality_input.csv')

# calculates the times each value appeared for a given name
a = pd.Series({col: data[col].value_counts() for col in data.columns})

for i, val in enumerate(a):
    # calculates the % of each, and rounds to 2 decimal places.
    a[i] = round(100*val/val.sum(), 2)

# converts all of the objects to a list called 'b'
b = pd.DataFrame(a.tolist())

# get the data frame size, and lists of headers for future use
line = list(b.columns.values)
name = list(b.index.values)
cols = len(b.columns)
rows = len(b)

for c in b.columns:
    b[c] = b[c].apply(lambda t: "{},{}%".format(c, t))

# copy the DataFrame to a list of lists, and creates a new list with out the NaN values
lol = b.values.tolist()
data_list = []
for items in lol:
    data_list.append([x for x in items if 'nan%' not in x])

# sort list values in descending values in every row, adds names back
for l in range(rows):
    sorting(data_list[l])
    data_list[l].insert(0, parameter.pop(0))

# sort list by value of the highest percentage of the second column in descending order
data_list.sort(key=lambda x: take_second(x[1]), reverse=True)

# writes the commonality table to a csv file
result_file = open("test.csv", 'w', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(result_file)
for item in data_list:
    wr.writerow(item)
```

note that i'm pretty new to python, so there must be a more efficient way for this program.